# Creating graph coordinate in LyX

Tags: lyx, diagrams

I'm looking for a way to create the following graph coordinate in `LyX`.

[image]

Which package should I use and How should I approach this problem?
I read some prevoius threads on how to do such things and I came across with `tikzpicture`. I read the docs but I didn't see any example on how to create similir things. Is it posssbile with `tikz`?

Comment: Try `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[-stealth] (-0.5,0) -- (5,0) node[right]{$Q_x$};
 \draw[-stealth] (0,-0.5) -- (0,5) node[above]{$P_x$};
 \draw[dashed] (2.2,3) -- (-0.25,3) node[left]{$P_0$};
 \draw (1,4) to[out=-70,in=160] (3,1) 
 node[left=1cm]{$D(\overline{P}_y,\overline{T},I_0)$};
 \draw (2,4) to[out=-70,in=155] (3.5,1) node[above right]{$\dots$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 2):

marmot already gave you a code sample in his comment, but since you're using LyX maybe you need to know how to insert it in it.

Open your document and choose `Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble` and add

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, positioning}
```

and click on `OK`.

Then choose `Insert --> TeX code` (or click on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) and insert this code where the cursor is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth] 
\draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (5,0) node[right]{$Q_x$}; 
\draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,5) node[above]{$P_x$}; 
\draw[name path=firstdemand] (.5,4.5) parabola[bend at end] (4,.5) node[above left=7pt and 44pt] {$D(\overline{P}_y,\overline{T},I_0)$};
\draw[name path=demand] (1.5,4.5) parabola[bend at end] (5,1) node[above right=14pt and -34pt] {$D(\overline{P}_y,\overline{T},I_1>I_0)$};
\path[name path=line] (0,3) -- (4,3);
\path [name intersections={of=demand and line,by=mypoint}];
\draw[dashed] (-.3,3) node[left] {$P_0$} -- (mypoint);
\path[name path=lowline] (0,2.5) -- (4,2.5);
\path [name intersections={of=firstdemand and lowline,by=mylowpoint}];
\draw[thick, ->] (mylowpoint) -- ++(.7,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

(my code is a little different from marmot's one).

Then click on `View`, and you'll get this result:

[image]